# How to edit Java Platform Package (Built-in API) source code?

Tags: java

As good as the Java API is, I need to change the code of some classes in the default API packages (for example `java.util.Scanner`) for a project I am working on.

Ideally, I would extend the classes I am interested and create my own sub-classes, but the classes I want to extend are declared 'final'. How do you suggest I do this? Will I get into trouble with the compiler if I customize the source code of these packages?

Comment: What do you want to change in the classes? I doubt that it's neccessary to change the API code...

Comment: With all respect, but why do you need to do this? I'm asking, because in most cases when somebody come up with such a request, there is more simple and straight solution.

Comment: @brimborium Various things, such as modifying the constructors, append return type of void methods to boolean to monitor flow of control, add my own methods to the classes, etc.

Comment: @bpgergo, besides my response above, I think it would be an experiment thing to do, regardless of the motivation.

Comment: You can re-build your own `rt.jar` to experiment but if you run your program with the "old" version it could (will) fail.

Comment: @jesterII Well you can always build your own java API using the provided code. But I can not see any advantage to that. If you really want extended features to a API class, build a wrapper class (like `JesterIIScanner` or so) that adds what you want... You can replace methods in there or just add new ones...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can, you should rather wrap and delegate, as suggested in another answer.  See the [Adapter Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

But there are of course ways to do this if you *really* need it.

A straightforward approach is to simply modify the code in downloaded sources and substitute your own version of a jar in the classpath.

Another option is to use aspect-oriented programming techniques, likely with [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) to intercept and modify calls as needed.

It might also be possible to hack together a solution using reflection and home-grown classloaders, but it will be painful to code.

All of these are however quite risky if you don't know what you're doing.  Frequently classes are made final for good reason.

If you tell us more specifically what it is you're hoping to change, we might be able to provide assistance in avoiding what you currently think you need.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. I will look further into AspectJ. There might be a better way achieve what I am doing than altering the API, but I would be interested in trying it nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

you really cant extend a final class..

if u really want to add a functionality by extending a class you can do it by modifying class src. from JDK and save it as your own class and use it.

Comment: This is the only answer that applies to the question, the rest are mostly preaching about not doing it.

Comment: @BaileyS -  Did you read my answer before downvoting it?  I preached not to do it, but also gave a few options for things to try (including this one) if it's really needed.

Comment: @Don Roby, you are right, if you edit your question I will change my vote to +1 :)

Answer (score -2):

Don't do that. Write your own code  which wraps around the original scanner and use that. To update internal packages, there is an `endorsed` directory property which you can provide at runtime.

Answer (score -2):

Never do it! Never change core classes. If class is final - use composition not inheritance.