# How can I set the SHA digest size in java.security.MessageDigest?

Tags: hash, java, sha

I am kinda playing with the SHA-1 algorithm. I want to find out differences and variations in the results if I change few values in the SHA-1 algorithm for a college report. I have found a piece of java code to generate hash of a text. Its done by importing

> java.security.MessageDigest

class. However, I want to change the h0-4 values and edit them but I don't know where can I find them? I had a look inside the MessageDigest class but couldn't find it there.  Please help me out!

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do that. Java doesn't provide any API for its [MessageDigest Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/), which can allow you change the values.

However, there are some workarounds (none of which I've ever tried). Take a look at this [answer to the question "*How to edit Java Platform Package (Built-in API) source code?*"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11081612/1382832)

Answer (score 0):

If you're playing around with tweaks to an algorithm, you shouldn't be using a built-in class implementing that algorithm. The class you mention is designed to implement standard algorithms for people who just want to use them in production; if you're *using* SHA-1 (or any cryptographic algorithm) instead of playing around and tweaking it, it's never a good idea to change the algorithm yourself (e.g. by changing the initial hash value), so the class does not support modifying those constants.

Just implement the algorithm yourself; from Wikipedia's pseudocode, it doesn't look like it's all that complicated. I know that "don't implement your own crypto, use a standard and well-tested implementation" is a common mantra here, but that only applies to production-type code -- if you're playing around with an algorithm to see what effect tweaking it has, you *should* implement it yourself, so you have more flexibility in modifying it and seeing the effect of the modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Basically adding to @Rahil's answer but too much for comments:

Even without API access, if `MessageDigest` were the implementation you could use reflection. But it's not.

Most of the java standard library is just commonly-useful classes in the usual way, e.g. `java.util.ArrayList` contains the implementation of ArrayList (or ArrayList<?> since 6), `java.io.FileInputStream` contains the implementation of FileInputStream (although it may use other classes in that implementation), etc. Java Cryptography uses a more complicated scheme where the implementations are not in the API classes but instead in "providers" that are mostly in their own jars (in JRE/lib and JRE/lib/ext) not rt.jar and mostly(?) don't have source in src.zip.

Thus the `java.security.MessageDigest` class does not have the code to implement SHA1, or SHA256, or MD5, etc etc. Instead it has code to search the JVM's current list of crypto providers to find an implementation of whatever algorithm is asked for, and instantiate and use that. Normally the list of providers used is set to (the list of) those included in the JRE distribution, although an admin or program can change it.
With the normal JRE7 providers, SHA1 is implemented by `sun.security.provider.SHA`.

In effect the API classes like `MessageDigest Signature Cipher KeyGenerator` etc function more like interfaces or facades by presenting the behavior that is common to possibly multiple underlying implementations, although in Java code terms they are actual classes and not interfaces.

This was designed back in 1990 or so to cope with legal restrictions on crypto in effect then, especially on export from the US. It allowed the base Java platform to be distributed easily because by itself it did no crypto. To *use* it -- and even if you don't do "real" crypto on user data in Java you still need things like verification of signed code -- you need to add some providers; you might have one set of providers, with complete and strong algorithms, used in US installations, and a different set, with fewer and weaker algorithms, used elsewhere. This capability is now much less needed since the US officially relaxed and in practice basically dropped enforcement about 2000, although there are periodically calls to bring it back. There is still one residual bit, however: JCE (in Oracle JREs) contains a policy that does not allow symmetric keys over 128 bits; to enable that you must download from the Oracle website and install an additional (tiny) file "JCE Unlimited Strength Policy".

**TLDR:** don't try to alter the JCE implementation. As @cpast says, in this case where you want to play with something *different from* the standard algorithm, *do* write your own code.